# Different commands shows different results. If my linux 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, 32-bit

The system of my VPS is centos 5. I want to know if it is 32bit or 64bit.

```
> uname -a
Thu May 13 13:49:53 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

looks like 64 bit.

But

```
> getconf WORD_BIT
32
```

Looks like 32 bit.

Which is correct?

---

**UPDATE**

I believe the linux of my VPS is 32 bit. Because I downloaded a 64bit mongodb, found it can't start. And when I downloaded a 32bit instead, it works well.

Comment: Why would you expect `getconf WORD_BIT` to tell you whether you have a 32-bit or a 64-bit OS? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends. It's possible `getconf` [doesn't return the correct value](http://marc.info/?l=redhat-list&m=111538052707152), and it's possible you have a 32-bit kernel on 64-bit hardware. I'd say, however, that the output of `uname` is what you should go by, as it states that you're running a 64-bit kernel.

Comment: I don't think it's possible that it's 32-bit kernel on 64-bit hardware if `uname -a` gives those results...

Answer (score 0):

`uname -a` shows whether the OS is 32/64 bit.

Comment: welcome! fyi, `getconf WORD_BIT` returns 32 on my 64 bit Ubuntu. Also `sizeof(int)` is 32 bits... maybe that's what the getconf command is reporting.

Comment: I'd think `sizeof(void*)` would be the indicator

Comment: `sizeof(void*)` is going to be 8 bytes for 64 bit architectures no? I don't know what `getconf WORD_BIT` does, and was guessing it may be related to the size of an int because that actually is 32 bits! Edit: (on my current 64 bit OS...)

Comment: Indeed, the size of an int is not the arch size. [This nice Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_\(computing\)#Table_of_word_sizes) shows how int sizes can be anywhere between ¼ word to 4 words on the 80486 family.

Comment: The question still remains, is `getconf WORD_BIT` defined as the size of an int, or does it have some other meaning?

Comment: It is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/limits.h.html) as the number of bits in an `int`.

Answer (score -1):

The glibc's `WORD_BIT` seems to be broken, because (in `xopen_lim.h`) it looks at `__INT_MAX__` instead of `__WORDSIZE` or `sizeof(__SWORD_TYPE)`.

To report the syscall personality of the current process, those commands are equivalent:

```
uname -m
arch
```

To change it, assuming your kernel supports it:

```
linux32
linux64
```

It is possible to have a 64bit kernel with a 32bit userland. To know what kind of kernel you have:

```
sudo file /proc/kcore
```

Your CPU:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: It's broken because it does exactly what the standard requires it to do?!

Comment: I looked at the standard link in your other comment. The definition (`Number of bits in a word or type int`) is ambiguous (and so is “exactly as required”), which makes it useless already; going with "size of an int" instead of "size of a word" as the name implies is a dubious choice.